# IDHTTPServer: In FireMonkey, how to I serve images from within the app as web images?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, indy

IDHTTPServer: In FireMonkey, how to I serve images from within the app as web images?

For example:  works with images stored in the filestructure. I don't want to have to save the images to the file structure before serving them. All help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a physical file on the filesystem.  In your `OnCommand...` handler, create an instance of a suitable `TStream` to hold the image data, like a `TMemoryStream`, and assign it to the `AResponseInfo.ContentStream` property.  And assign the `AResponseInfo.ContentType` property to describe the type of data you are sending, like `image/png`, `image/jpeg`, etc.

Comment: Remy, in Delphi I can add images to the resources. Can I do something similar to hold the images and the stream them?

Comment: Yes: [How to store images in FireMonkey?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426914/)